# Android Marshmallow can't use pm with Superuser

Tags: android, root, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-package-managers

I have an Android application that's been requiring root access to access functionality from the package manager. Because user applications can't get requisite permissions, I've assumed that the user has a rooted phone, and from there I was using Runtime.exec() to run pm w/ su.

This worked with Lollipop, but starting with Marshmallow it looks like this won't work anymore; regular user applications can't call, for example, pm install, but if I run the command on a root terminal pm returns an error saying it can't talk to the PackageManager. Logcat has a failure in getService from com.android.commands.pm.Pm

Is this a new security restriction in Marshmallow or an issue with SuperSu? Is the only way to do this now going through Android for Work as a DeviceOwner? I was hoping to keep everything confined to being a root app and not having to do device owner or custom builds.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually came back to look at this again and unfortunately found it was due to an older version of SuperSu. At the time Marshmallow had just come out so I assume it was a compatibility issue with the su binary. I'm currently using SuperSu 2.65 and everything appears to be working as expected once again

Comment: I know this is late but I am having the same issue as well. But do you know how you would have SuperSU installed with Marshmallow?